# Clarification on ROS2 argument types for srv/sub callbacks

Tags: ros2, c++

I need some clarifications on the type of arguments to use in callbacks for service and subscriptions in C++. I’m considering both service input and subscriptions, because, from my understanding, what I’m asking should apply to both. If I’m mistaken, please explain me why.

Let’s consider a topic with messages of type `T` (for instance `std_msgs::msg::String or some custome type, it shouldn’t matter). From what I’ve seen, a callback for the subscriber to a topic of type T will have, in general, one of the following 3 types:

1. `const T&`
2. `const std::shared_ptr<T>`
3. `T::ConstSharedPtr`, which should be an alias for `std::shared_ptr<const T>`

What are the main differences among this types? What I need to consider when choosing among them?

From my understanding:

- (3) allows for efficient intra-process communication (no copy made), and thus is preferable with large messages
- In (2), constness of a shared_ptr means that the ownership of the object is not shared (and kept), but the content of the pointer is still modifiable. This does not allow zero copy.
- for zero-copy to happen I can also use std::unique_ptr, but I need to be sure that only one subscriber exists on that topic.
- for a service response I cannot use (3), since the pointed object is const.

Are the above sentences correct?